# Ubuntu 20.04, simple scan does not detect scanner

Tags: 20.04, hp, scanner

Got ubuntu 20.04

Got HP Deskjet 2540

Got HP Officejet 3830

Connected via USB

All worked fine in Ubuntu 19.10

In Ubuntu 20.04 simple scan gives error "Failed to scan Unable to connect to scanner. " Also error code 5012

Doesn't work with HPLIP, doesn't work with preinstalled ubuntu drivers.

Help please  ?

Comment: I have posted an answer to a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262946). It deals with a different device which is connected through the network, not with a USB cable, however, I think it can possibly still be useful to someone ending up here.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out.

Comment: hmm, none of that works for me. I prefer USB anyway as it's simpler. Sometimes ubuntu mess things up. I still love it though.

Answer (score 11):

I have found a workaround for this problem that has really annoyed me for three months now on my `HP Envy 4500` with embedded scanner connected via USB (printing was affected too).
Several bug reports have linked this problem to a conflict between hplip (HP linux drivers) and ippusbxd (Daemon for IPP USB printer support)

- [Simple Scan stops working after upgrade to 20.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/simple-scan/+bug/1873748)
- [USB scanning broken on focal --> hpmud and ippusbxd conflict](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/1871011)
- [Printer cannot be set up as long as the package ippusbxd is installed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ippusbxd/+bug/1876289)

I tried uninstaling `hplip` and `ippusbxd` separately to see what was best, but the only working solution was really to uninstall `ippusbxd` as it solved all my problems of multiple printers being displayed and reappearing even if i deleted them.

```bsh
> sudo apt purge ippusbxd
```

Note : I had to disconnect my printer from the USB port and to reinstall it after having purged `ippusbxd` and every printer definition that was left.

And so the scanning problem is solved too even if i still got the same annoying modal error pop up after each single page scan (but it's working)..

Comment: Thanks for that answer Zipang purging ippusbxd has done the trick for my HP 2634 in 20:04
:ThumbsUP:
You win the internet for the month

Comment: Also Worked in Lubuntu 20.04 as well.

Comment: thanks! that works! and worth is to mention that the  best is  to download the newest drivers from hp directly, better don't relay on default ubuntu repo because there are older hplip

Comment: I was struggling for hours with my HP Neverstop Laser MFP 1200n before I found this gold answer!

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with a Brother MFC-250C on Ubuntu 20.4. Printing worked, but no scanner found. Multifunction device connected via USB. Solved it by installing libusb-0.1-4. Maybe this will help in your case too.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem  took out USB and set up WiFi and it now scans and prints perfectly , HP envy 5010 and use Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Ah, thanks Neil,, maybe I should try that.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with HP Envy Inspire 7200e all-in-one. My system is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with current updates.

Having set up Wifi the printer side worked fine and ran the usual tests, but SimpleScanner kept saying there were no scanners available.

This how I finally got it to work:

First I tried re-installing the current (3.22.2) hplip. Forget it. HPlip claims that the 7200e is supported from 3.21.10, but it was looking for files like python-pyqt5 which it couldn't find because it isn't part of the standard downloads under 20.04: Synaptic's Package Manager supplies python3-pyqt5.  As a result it wouldn't install. Deleted HPlip.

I also purged ippusbxd, setting the 7200 up via USB as HP suggested didn't work.

Instead, following advice at https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2452452.html I ran a barrage of tests, which helped some but didn't get things working. I would recommend that you read that through (it's a bit confusing in parts) because there are some good hints.

In the end I re-installed sane and added sane-airscan and replaced ippusbxd  with ipp-usb (from the snap store) as the link recommends, **BUT** I had to purge Simple scanner and re-install it (as Document Scanner) from snapd.

Once re-installed the system found the scanner and it both scans and prints as you would expect it to.

Hope this helps!